# PHP SAML Post Variable Not Showing After Redirect

Tags: php, post, saml

I'm working with a SSO Saml authentication flow which looks as follows:

> 1. User sends SAMLRequest
> 2. User is redirected to IdP login page
> 3. User submits login details
> 4. IdP authenticates and redirects to my consumer assertion processing page
> 5. Access token extracted and submitted for a token to interact with API

I'm stuck on step 5. In fiddler, I can see the request header being sent with the required SAMLResponse posted, but it does not show in $_POST, $_GET and I've tried file_get_contents('php://input'). The response is the result of a 301 redirect.

The incoming header request with the required SAMLResponse redirected (301) to my assertion consumer page looks as follows. I can't figure out how to extract the posted parameter SAMLResponse?

> POST http://localhost/xxxxxxxxxxx
>   Host: localhost
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 7710
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Origin: null
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Cookie: optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1463724346007r0.9674156716176872; ajs_anonymous_id=%22c336991a-286a-4278-8cb2-3d00d784f376%22; optimizelySegments=%7B%225943211328%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%225934960299%22%3A%22false%22%2C%225952160221%22%3A%22gc%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; ajs_user_id=null; ajs_group_id=null; _ga=GA1.1.1336717339.1458634274; PHPSESSID=imtffdda2a6g576rtd0vpb8ro2
>
> SAMLResponse=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I've been scanning the web for a week but have not found a solution. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems you lose the request data during step 4. A redirect doesn't forward the data submitted to the page. Perhaps you need to save the information before redirecting.

Comment: I was unintentionally redirecting due to inadvertently omitting a trailing / on my consumer url. Thanks for you response!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was missing a trailing / on my consumer assertion url which of course meant the server was redirecting to index.php resulting in the loss of post vabriables.